# Automatically Render Symfony2 Templates for Controller Actions like Zend Framework

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, symfony, twig

I am coming from a Zend Framework background, and the process for creating a page is:

1. Create a controller
2. Create an empty action
3. Create a folder for the controller
4. Create a file matching the name of the controller action and place it in the directory for the controller

When you access the application via http://host/controller/action the view file is automatically rendered.

Is it possible for me to do this within Symfony2 so that I do not have to create routing entries for each controller/action? and automatically render the twig templates for each action?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@Template` annotation from the [SensioFrameworkExtraBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html).

```
 class MyController extends Controller {
     /**
      * @Template()
      */
    public function myAction() { 
        return array(); 
    }
 }
```

The template is `Resources/views/My/my.twig.html`. Note that you have to return something in the action method.